# Running test in R with a time window

Tags: r

I am trying to get the time series of the lepage test statistic from a running lepage test.

The time window is 9 years.

Here's the data that I am using (1961 to 2009)

```
structure(list(Year = 1961:2009, Winter = c(11.5714803313, 9.3664362519, 
14.3399332592, 14.1548003072, 10.0271889401, 16.1278801843, 7.5481110699, 
2.6131336406, 14.9045698925, 11.9352150538, 19.3715609937, 8.3156298003, 
20.686328725, 9.9734639017, 18.7517612162, 19.7309907834, 4.5365207373, 
13.7009600614, 8.3644790508, 8.325, 8.4933179724, 9.4112135177, 
5.2000370782, 8.7163210445, 9.0083333333, 3.449078341, 10.2567296997, 
13.4682795699, 6.877764977, 6.4040706605, 6.9916944753, 6.4950076805, 
16.0668202765, 7.3995391705, 18.5592880979, 7.4816052227, 3.5526113671, 
24.7658218126, 17.7594364108, 18.2832565284, 10.2024577573, 5.6401689708, 
8.047942158, 7.8697388633, 18.4008832565, 9.9166282642, 27.385168706, 
21.0661290323, 4.7410138249)), .Names = c("Year", "Winter"), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-49L))
```

I am using the nonpar package for the lepage test 
[Link to package](https://rdrr.io/github/tpepler/nonpar/man/lepage.test.html)

I don't know how to implement this in R. 
Here is my script so far (this is wrong):

```
 library(nonpar)
 dat<-read.csv("test.csv",header=T)
 x <- as.numeric(dat$Winter)

 for (i in 1:length(x)){
 #window
 n = 9
     stat<-lepage.test(x[i],x[i:i+n])$obs.stat
  }
 return(stat) 
 }
```

What I want to do:

[1] Perform lepage test with a window of 9 years. In the test data above, the calculation should only start at 1970 (1961 to 1969 and 1970 to 1978). Then, the value for 1971 is the lepage test between the data from (1962 to 1970) and (1971 to 1979),and so on.

[2] I also tried using the "rollapplyr" function from the zoo package but I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
library(zoo)
test<-rollapplyr(x, 9, function(u) lepage.test(u,u+1)$obs.stat)
```

[3] I'll appreciate any help on how I can implement this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
test<-rollapplyr(x, 9, function(u) lepage.test(u,u+1)$obs.stat)
```

you are getting the `lepage.test` of the values in the current window with the same values increased by 1. You may do the following instead.

```
library(zoo)
library(nonpar)
x <- zoo(dat$Winter)
y <- rollapply(x, 9, c)
pairs <- lapply(1:(nrow(y)-9), function(i) list(x1 = y[i,], x2 = y[i+9,]))
pairs2 <- lapply(pairs, function(x) lapply(x, as.numeric))
test <- sapply(1:32, function(i) lepage.test(pairs2[[i]]$x1, pairs2[[i]]$x2)$obs.stat)
test
#  [1] 1.8182 2.5782 0.8046 0.2214 0.9449 0.6128 2.4022 7.0955 6.8560 7.8285 5.5361
# [12] 3.2331 2.6603 2.1228 0.9856 0.6616 1.3692 2.1103 1.1509 0.7352 0.5057 1.5349
# [23] 3.8019 4.7344 2.2081 2.3770 0.1579 1.1430 3.8876 3.1820 1.8182 0.1435
```

Comment: awesome!Many thanks for the help!. I cant edit the post but it should be: pairs2 <- lapply(pairs, function(x) lapply(x, as.numeric))